# can someone help me here? im just a beginner and im kinda confused

Tags: python, while-loop

```
while True:
    decision = input("Would you like to repeat? Yes or No? ")
    if decision == "YES".casefold():
        print("")
    elif decision != "YES".casefold() or decision != "NO".casefold():
        print("Please type yes or no")
    elif decision == "NO".casefold():
        break
```

The process repeats even if the input is neither `yes` or `no`.

Comment: Look at your condition: `decision != "YES".casefold() or decision != "NO".casefold()`. Since `decision` cannot be both `YES` and `NO` at the same time, this is always `True`. You should change `or` to `and`. You are `casefold`ing the wrong thing by the way.

Comment: Set `decision = decision.lower()`, then check for 'yes' or 'no'.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is meant to be a knowledge repository, so ["Can someone help me" is not really a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341). Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    decision = input("Would you like to repeat? Yes or No? ").lower()
    if decision == "yes":
        print("OK")
        break
    elif decision == "no":
        break
    print("Please type yes or no")
```

Answer (score 1):

Casefold method has to be applied on `decision` and not on `"YES"` or `"NO"`.

#### Workaround 1:

Instead of using `and` operator, you should use `or` operator.
This is because `or` will always return `True` in your case.

```py
while True:
    decision = input("Would you like to repeat? Yes or No? ")
    if decision.casefold() == "yes":
        print("")
    elif decision.casefold() != "yes" and decision.casefold() != "no":
        print("Please type yes or no")
    elif decision.casefold() == "no":
        break
```

#### Workaround 2:

If you would like to not change `or` to `and`, you can swap the 2nd elif and 3rd elif statements to make the program work fine.

```py
while True:
    decision = input("Would you like to repeat? Yes or No? ")
    if decision.casefold() == "yes":
        print("")
    elif decision.casefold() == "no":
        break
    elif decision.casefold() != "yes" or decision.casefold() != "no":
        print("Please type yes or no")
```

#### Better solution:

Instead of converting decision to lowercase everytime, convert it once in the beginning.
The below code is more readable.

```py
while True:
    decision = input("Would you like to repeat? Yes or No? ").casefold()
    if decision == "yes":
        print("")
    elif decision == "no":
        break
    else:
        print("Please type yes or no")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    # apply casefold() to decision to clean up the input
    decision = input("Would you like to repeat? Yes or No? ").casefold()
    if decision != "yes" and decision != "no":
        print("Please type yes or no")
        continue # if no valid answer, go back to top to ask again
    if decision == "no":
        break    # if got a 'no', exit from 'while' loop
    # now we do our "yes" processing...
```

Other possible forms of the above "if-yes-no" are as follows:
if decision not in ("yes", "no"):
if "yes" != decision != "no":

Answer (score 0):

Your second `elif` will always evaluate to `True`. This is because `decision` can only have one value. Thus, it will *always* be not equal to either `YES` or `NO`. Instead you should do a `==` comparison like this

```
while True:
    decision = input("Would you like to repeat? Yes or No? ").lower()
    if decision == "yes":
        print("")
    elif decision == "no":
        break
    print("Please type yes or no")
```